# PDF layer creation from an SVG

Tags: angularjs, pdf, svg

I'm creating an SVG dynamically in Angular 4 which I want to turn into a PDF on the server side. At the moment I'm sending the SVG element data through this [link](https://alafr.github.io/SVG-to-PDFKit/examples/demo.htm) to see what the PDF may look like.

The problem is that the PDF that is created, when opened doesn't appear to have any layers associated with it.

My question is what type of element do I need to create, or add metadata to an existing element, in the SVG to get the layers to appear? I've tried just defining things as groups and placing everything I need associated with it inside.

Ideally I want 3 layers to exist in the PDF - namely Artwork, Outline & Annotations. Does anyone have any guidance as to how this should be structured?

Thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed that Optional Content Groups (OCGs or "Layers") are supported in SVG-to-PDFKit? It's not on the supported features list. https://github.com/alafr/SVG-to-PDFKit

Comment: No I haven't but I had an example a while ago, which I made, that when opened in Adobe had the layers there. Optional Content Group gives me something to research